# Relation between two definitions of primary modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, $M$ be an $A$-module and $N \leq M$. There are two definitions of primary modules:

1) $M/N$ is coprimary (i.e., every zero divisor is nilpotent);

2) $\text{Ann}_A(N)$ is a primary ideal of $A$.

The first definition is the usual one, however the second one appears in some linear algebra books (for instance, Roman's "Advanced Linear Algebra").

Of course, definition 1) is just for submodules of $M$ while definition 2) is for any module $N$. So what I'm really asking is if there is any reasonable way of matching these two definitions in the sense that $N$ satisfies 2 iff there exists some (special) module $M$ (not any $M$) associated to $N$ that makes 1) true.

I'm interested mainly in the case of $A$ Noetherian or even the case of $A$ being a PID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your "clarifications" don't improve the question at all: "*Let A be a commutative ring, M be an A-module and N≤M.*" and "*definition 2) is for any module N.*" are conflicting each other. Moreover, the zero submodule is never primary from definition 2) which is not so fun. And last but not least: "*There are two definitions of primary modules*" is a novelty, since people are talking about primary *sub*modules.

Comment: Meanwhile I've checked the book and I've realized what suggested you the definition 2): in the theory of f.g. modules over PIDs people are talking about the $p$-primary components of modules, and this made you believe that you could take it as a definition for primary submodules. Well, IMO this is a wrong choice because the primary components are only a few and their direct sum is the module, so their properties are completely different from those of primary submodules.

Comment: @user26857 It's not just this. Why there is the definition of prime modules and there isn't a definition of primary modules? This is what bother me.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but the way you wanted to go is not right. (Anyway, if I'll have some time I'll think to this question which sounds better than the posted one.)

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment otherwise I would. But I think it must be a typo, in the sense that (2) is supposed to be: $\mathrm{Ann}_A(M/N)$ is a primary ideal of $A$.

Then it seems rather tautological to prove that (1) implies (2) supposed to be that $R$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated. Indeed, we may assume that $N=0$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the unique associated prime  of $M$. Then $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal over $I=\mathrm{Ann}_A(M)$, in particular an associated prime of $A/I$. To prove that $\mathfrak{p}$ is the unique associated prime of $A/I$ it suffices to prove that any $x\notin\mathfrak{p}$ is a nonzero divisor on $A/I$. But suppose that $y\in A\setminus I$ such that $xy\in I$. Then we can find $m\neq 0$ such that $ym\neq 0$. But clearly $xym=0$ which implies that $x$ is a nonzero divisor on $M$ - a contradition to the fact that $M$ is coprimary.

The other implication "(2) implies (1)" does not always hold put it holds if in addition to the previous assumptions $M$ has no embedded primes. Indeed, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be the unique associated prime of $A/I$ then $\mathfrak{p}$ is also associated to $M$. Suppose that $x\notin\mathfrak{p}$ with $xm=0$ for some $m\neq 0$. Then $x\in\mathfrak{q}$ for some associated prime $\mathfrak{q}$ of $M$ different from $\mathfrak{p}$. But since $\mathfrak{p}=\sqrt{I}\subseteq\mathfrak{q}$ it follows that $\mathfrak{q}$ is an embedded prime. Therefore such an $x$ does not exists and it follows that every element not in $\mathfrak{p}$ is a nonzerodivisor on $M$ which means that $M$ is coprimary.

Even if $A$ is a PID the implication "(2) implies (1)" is false. For instance let $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ for some prime $p$. Then $\mathrm{Ann}_A(M)=0$ and $A$ is coprimary. But $M$ has associated primes $(0)$ and $(p)$ and is therefore not coprimary.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for your answer, but this is not a typo. In a linear algebra books (Roman's "Advanced Linear Algebra" for instance, though I've seen this in other books too),  $N$ is defined to be primary if $\text{Ann}_A (N) $ is a primary ideal of $A$, where $A = k[x]$ and $k$ is a field. So I was hoping that this definition would coincide with the usual one. Furthermore, this definition seems more natural, since it just looks like a generalization of the definition of a prime modules.

Comment: If you take $N$ to be coprimary if $\mathrm{Ann}_A(N)$ is a primary ideal that matches with the improvement I gave. Then $N$ is a primary submodule of $M$ if $M/N$ is coprimary if $\mathrm{Ann}_A(M/N)$ is a primary ideal. But you can't say that $N$ is a primary submodule of $M$ if $\mathrm{Ann}_A(N)$ is a primary ideal since the later condition does not at all depend on $M$. You should change the question.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I was thinking in something like: $N$ is a primary module if there exists a module $M$ such that $N$ is a primary submodule of $M$. I just want to make sense of why the second definition appears in some books, maybe it's just coincidence. So I'm just trying to match this definition of primary module (2) with the definition of primary submodule (1) in a compatible way. Any idea?

Comment: But if I change my question, it would not be my question. As I said, I want to know how to relate the two definitions that I've written. The question is ill formulated because 1) is for submodules and 2) is for modules. So I'm asking for a well defined definition that matches with these two. For instance, it could be something like $N$ satisfies 2 if there exists some (universal in some sense) module $M$ associated to $N$ that makes it a primary submodule of $M$. The point is that there is a definition of prime modules and there is no definition of primary modules (just submodules).